# Data is undefined in my promise could not set Error properly [API problem/Front Problem ? ]

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

what i'm trying to do is to signup my user using simple form ,but suddenly i get this error also it seems that data (promise argument ) is undefined ,
**Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined**

(forgive my terminology)

frontend

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import {signup} from '../../actions/auth'

const SignupComponent = () =>{
   const [values, setValues] = useState({
      name: "Fares",
      email: "essayehfares@gmail.com",
      password: "dccihdss",
      error: "",
      loading: false,
      message: "",
      showForm: true,
   });

   const {name,email,password,error,loading,message,showForm} = values 

   const handleSubmit = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        setValues({...values,loading:true,error:false})
        const user ={name,email,password}
        signup(user)
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data); //!!!!!!!this promise is returning 'undefined' , !!!!!!!!!!!!
            if(data.error){
                setValues({...values,error:data.error,loading:false});
            }else{
                setValues({
                  ...values,
                  name: "",
                  email: "",
                  password: "",
                  error: "",
                  loading: false,
                  message: data.message,
                  showForm: false,
                });
            }
        });
    }
    const handleChange = name => e => {
        setValues({ ...values, error:false, [name]: e.target.value });
    }
    const signupForm = () =>{
        return (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                value={name}
                onChange={handleChange('name')}
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Type your name"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                value={email}
                onChange={handleChange("email")}
                type="email"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Type your email"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                value={password}
                onChange={handleChange('password')}
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Type your password"
              />
            </div>
                <div>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary">Signup</button>
                </div>
          </form>
        );
    }
    return (
        <React.Fragment>{signupForm()}</React.Fragment>
    )
};

export default SignupComponent;
```

signup method (isomorphic-fetch)

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import {API} from '../config'

export const signup = (user)=>{
    return fetch(`${API}/signup`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Contnet-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(user)
    }).
    then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

Auth API

```
exports.signup = (req, res) => {
  user.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).exec((err, user) => {
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Email is taken",
      });
    }
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;
    let username = shortId.generate();
    let profile = `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/profile/${username}`;

    let newUser = new User({ name, email, password, profile, username });

    newUser.save((err, success) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: "something is not correct",
        });
      }
      res.json({
        // user:success,
        message: "Signup success ! please Sign in ",
      });
    });
  });
};
exports.signin = (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  //check if the user exist
  User.findOne({ email }).exec((err, user) => {
    if (err || !user) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "User with that email does not exist , Please signup",
      });
    }
    //authentification
    if(!user.authenticate(password)){
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: "Email and password don't match",
          });
    }
    // generate token and send to client 
    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id },process.env.JWT_SECRET,{expiresIn:'1d'});

    res.cookie("token", token, { expiresIn: "1d" });
 
    const {_id,username,name,email,role} = user
    return res.json({
        token,
        user:{_id,username,name,email,role}
    })
});
};
```

// FrontEnd dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "es6-promise-promise": "^1.0.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "next": "^10.1.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "reactstrap": "^8.9.0"
  },
```

backend dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-jwt": "^6.0.0",
    "express-validator": "^6.10.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "shortid": "^2.2.16"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your signup method is an asynchronous call, it should return a promise. If you are already handling `.then` call in your `handleSubmit` method, then you need to remove the `.then` call from the signup method. Below is the updated code

```js
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import {API} from '../config'

// now, since fetch returns a promise, and signup method is returning fetch
// it is returning a promise on which we can call `.then` and `.catch` accordingly
export const signup = async (user) => {
    return fetch(`${API}/signup`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Contnet-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
}
```